# non-pointer error in Go not sure what it means

Tags: pointers, go

I have a function that takes a json decoder and an interface as its arguements, and i am decoding to a struct that is passed on the interface. Like so:

```
func DecodeJSON(decoder *json.Decoder, i interface{}) bool {
    if c, ok := i.(User); ok {
        err := decoder.Decode(c)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return false //err is not nil
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Usage of the function:

```
// Register test
func HandleRequest(w rest.ResponseWriter, r *rest.Request) {

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    user := User{}
    if DecodeJSON(decoder, user) {    
        fmt.Println("success")
}
```

Error i am getting:

```
json: Unmarshal(non-pointer main.User)
```

Bit confused by this message since my DecodeJSON is not taking a pointer for `user`. So am not sure what i have done wrong with my code. Hope some one can explain so i can understand my mistake.

Comment: You need to use a pointer to a user to decode the data in, otherwise the decoded data gets decoded in a copy of the object that gets deleted when the function returns.

Comment: I originally tried with `user := &User{}` and func with `i *interface{}`  But it would not take the type so i got real confused. I haven't added a return yet because i just wanted to fix the error issue first.

Comment: The empty interface can store any value, including pointers, so `*interface{}` doesn't really makes sense, because you don't want a pointer to an interface, you just need to use the interface to store a pointer.

Comment: Also see https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal which basically says that if you don't provide a pointer to decode into, you'll get an error.

Comment: Why does everyone down vote these questions when it comes to `go` language. So much elitism from people on this site these days. Heaven forbid some one is trying to learn and asks for help anymore.

Comment: Aside: a *json.Decoder argument seems odd. It it more common to pass an io.Reader. There is only one way to create a *json.Decoder -- json.NewDecoder -- so forcing all callers to do this is inconvenient.

Comment: I was just following the rest library example so i don't really know what the right decision is =/

Comment: @Sir I think the reason people downvote this questions in Go, is because it's a really small language with really good documentation to get started (you can do the tour of go and read in the go blog about all the "tricky" types: slices, channels, etc.. in less than an hour) but a lot of beginners don't bother with that and a lot of them don't even put the code on their questions and a high number are issues with people just ignoring error on function calls. I don't think your question is bad but a lot of them are and it's making the SO Go community increasingly intolerant of beginner questions

Comment: I do get the impression that Go shouldn't be the chosen language for beginners (which i am), it feels elitist, its quite tricky to pick up and understand from the docs which is a wall of text for the most part. I do find the documentation a bit less than helpful if you don't have good understanding of programming already. I prefer the way for example C# docs are where it explains has info and example code usages. Go often lacks reasonably examples and its very hit and miss for all the GitHub libraries on the quality of documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a pointer to a user to decode the data in, otherwise the decoded data gets decoded in a copy of the object that gets deleted when the function returns.

```
func DecodeJSON(decoder *json.Decoder, i interface{}) bool {
    if c, ok := i.(*User); ok {
        err := decoder.Decode(c)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return false //err is not nil
        }
    }
    return false
}

// Register test
func HandleRequest(w rest.ResponseWriter, r *rest.Request) {

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    user := &User{}
    if DecodeJSON(decoder, user) {    
        fmt.Println("success")
}
```

Leave the interface parameter as is, just use a pointer when you pass the User and when you get the user from the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you'd better change your function signature to 

`func DecodeJSON(decoder *json.Decoder, user *User) bool`

This will (1) eliminate explicit runtime cast, and (2) make your code less ambiguous and safe and compile-time checked.

Comment: That limits the function to only accept a `user` struct which would defeat the entire purpose of the function. My function is  suppose to take ANY struct i give it and decode json to it.